# VUE.js Routing Configuration

Tags: vue.js, routes, vue-component, vue-router

I am creating an application where I have a list of users, when I click on a single user, it takes me to that specific users profile. I am using ASP.NET Core API with Vue.js as my front end. My API is working so when I click on the user, I am able to see the data coming from my database using Chrome dev Tools and Postman. However, once my page redirects to their profile, that page is blank. When I look in dev tools, I can see that its hitting my API and getting the correct information when looking at the preview tab.

So my question is, why is my page blank and not providing me with that users information. Can someone help me look at my routing, I think that is where my issue is?

I am passing their lastName as the param, but eventually I will pass a unique id

[image]

Here is my Profile.vue page, this is where I should see the users profile

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <v-card>
      <v-data-table :headers="headers"
                    :items="records"
                    :search="search">
        <template slot="items" slot-scope="records">
          <td class="text-xl-left">{{ records.item.firstName }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-left">{{ records.item.email }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-left">{{ records.item.phone }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-left">{{ records.item.city }}</td>
          <td class="justify-center layout px-0"></td>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
    </v-card>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import api from '../store/api.js'

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        records: {},
        headers: [
          { text: 'Full Name', value: 'fullName' },
          { text: 'Email', value: 'email' },
          { text: 'Phone', value: 'phone' },
          { text: 'City', value: 'city' },
          { text: 'Actions', value: 'name', sortable: false }
        ]
      }
    },
    async created() {
      this.GetInquiriesByUser()
    },
    methods: {
      async GetInquiriesByUser() {
        this.loading = true

        try {
          this.records = await api.GetInquiriesByUser()
        } finally {
          this.loading = false
        }
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

I am using router.push to route me to the user profile from the previous page (the list)

```
editItem(lastName) {
        this.$http.get(`http://localhost:61601/api/GetInquiry/${lastName}`)
        this.$router.push({ path: `/Profile/${lastName}` }) 
      },
```

Here is my routes.js file - I really think my error is in this, but cant seem to figure it out.

```
export const routes = [
  { name: 'home', path: '/', component: HomePage, display: 'Home', icon: 'home' },
  { name: 'AdminInquiry', path: '/Inquiry/AdminInquiry', component: AdminInquiry, display: 'Admin', icon: 'list' },
  { name: 'Profile', path: `/Profile/:lastName`, component: Profile }
]
```

Comment: what router mode are you using?

Comment: Do you not need to await your http call in `editItem`?

Comment: I am using Vue.use(VueRouter). Is this what you are referring to when you mean router mode? @Daniel

Comment: @DilbarC he means history or hash mode.

Comment: the router has two ways it can be used, the default is the `hash` mode, which uses routes after the `#` character, the other mode is `history` which requires server interaction. I'm guessing you're using the hash mode. https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html

Comment: Looks like I am just on the default hash @StevenB.

Comment: Yes is hash mode, just the default @Daniel

Comment: @DilbarC do your vue devtools show `this.records` being populated?

Comment: I just checked, and looks like `this.records` is not being populated on the Profile page. @StevenB.

Comment: @DilbarC Try removing async from the created hook.

Comment: just tried that, unfortunate its the same result. Thanks for the suggestions! @StevenB.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that this is an issue with the router setup not matching your backend. The blank page can be indicative of this.

for your vue page, the default Router mode is `hash` which uses a url hack, which is that changes to anything after `#` character (with some caveats) do not cause the browser to redirect. So when you're going from let's say `localhost:80#/Inquiry/AdminInquiry` to `localhost:80#/Profile/Drumpf`, the change is handled entirely by the vue application. If however if you navigate from `localhost:80/Inquiry/AdminInquiry` to `localhost:80/Profile/Drumpf` the navigation is more complex. The js *can* handle the transition by artificially changing the url without an actual redirect taking place, if the event is triggered using js. If, however, that happens using a standard anchor, your browser redirect gets triggered, and it's up to your server-side application to handle what route is passed to the js app.

It looks like you're looking to implement `history` mode. This requires defining the mode as `history` in the vue app, and making the appropriate changes for your ASP, nginx, or apache to handle the routes. More info here: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html